# Installation failed due to low priviledge on Win8

Tags: java, installation, uac

I am using Java code to install an EXE program on Win8, by executing this command "java -jar installapp.jar" in CML.  The command line window is NOT opened by "Run as administrator", but the current user is a member of administrator group.

However, in the same CML window, if I install the EXE directly, it works.  It just fails when the installation is executed by Java.

So anyone can give me a tip?

Thanks a lot,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

To correctly install an application which includes writing to system-protected areas can't be done without elevating through UAC. That means the CML window must be *Run as administrator*.

Java executables are marked with manifest which requests `asInvoker` privileges. So the process would start with administrator tokens dropped if the parent process wasn't elevated. It's the whole point of UAC: even if you are member of Administrators group, you don't get the full, unlimited privileges until you elevate.

What do you mean by *"install the exe directly"?*

Comment: Thanks for the response!  By "install the exe directly" I meant to execute appinstall.exe directly in CML, instead of the calling chain "CML->Java->Jar file->appinstall.exe".  Now I have elevated the priviledge and can do the installation, however, I dont want to be running as administrator, but just elevated with a particular priviledge that can connect socket, install app, write system files.  Does Microsoft provide any way to achieve this fine-grain accessing control?  Thanks

Comment: It's a bit weird… And if you run `appinstall.exe` directly in CML, it is able to write to Program Files. My guess is that in this case `appinstall.exe` is run with Virtualization on, and actually writes to `VirtualStore` instead of the intended location.

Comment: Fine-grain access control? Both yes and no. You can configure your system so that a user, even administrator, has access only to particular parts of the system. However, being administrator, it is possible to override these permissions. Usually you can connect to a socket (unless Firewall denies). But to install apps in all-users, or system, level you have to elevate to have full admin rights. There's no need to elevate for per-user installs. Writing system files is discouraged, you shouldn't do it: you can break system or other applications.